# Elastic Search Clients NEST vs Curl vs HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, curl, httpwebrequest, nest

I am relatively new to ES (6.3.0), while going through various documentations I noticed & tried retrieving the data from ES using NEST and HttpWebRequest (C# .NET Core).

Currently our use case is to retrieve bulk documents from ES using SearchAsync & Sliced Scroll kind of API which can also be implemented using Curl or HttpWebRequest.

Which client we can consider for our production application (.NET core based running on RHEL ) considering going forward we could have complex query which could be created on run time based on user requirement.

Comment: Use whichever method you're comfortable with. If you'd like to build dynamic queries within a .NET Core application however, using NEST seems like a sensible starting point, as it will allow you to compose complex queries with types, as opposed to fiddling with JSON strings and query syntax

Comment: Thanks Russ that was helpful. My only left doubt is :Is it actually recommended to use tools like curl or raw http classes in code (C# or Java ) to communicate with ES ? And in case if we do so isn't we are reinventing some thing which is already implemented by ES commuity (NEST)?

Comment: NEST is an Elasticsearch client for .NET officially supported by Elastic with contributions from the community. You should weigh up the relative merits of the the ways that you are considering to interact with the Elasticsearch APIs. Considering you're relatively new to Elasticsearch, in my opinion, you would likely get a lot of value out of using NEST, for the reasons outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447728